# My WordPress plugin can't create all the database tables I want on activation

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create a plugin in WP and I need to create some tables with it. The problem is that when I use collation utf8_general_ci, the tables creation stops and does not create the 5th and the 6th table. The other tables execute normally. I can't find what's wrong.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: UniTimetable
Plugin URI: 
Description: A plugin to create timetable for lessons and classrooms
Version: 1.0
Author: Fotis Kokkoras, Antonis Roussos
Author URI: https://www.linkedin.com/pub/antonis-roussos/47/25b/9a5
License: GPLv2
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'utt_install' );


function utt_install(){
        $sql = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_periods` (
  `periodID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` YEAR NOT NULL COMMENT 'το έτος - έτσι θα μπορεί να κρατηθεί και ιστορικό σε βάθος χρόνου',
  `semester` ENUM('Ε','Χ') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Εαρινό, Χειμερινό',
  PRIMARY KEY (`periodID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_subjects` (
  `subjectID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'το επίσημο όνομα του μαθήματος',
  `type` ENUM('Θ','Ε','ΑΠ') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Θεωρία, Εργαστήριο, Άσκηση-Πράξη',
  `semester` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'το εξάμηνο σπουδών στο οποίο απευθύνεται το μάθημα',
  `is_enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'εαν το μάθημα είναι ενεργό - η εφαρμογή θα προβάλει μόνο τα ενεργά μαθήματα',
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjectID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_groups` (
  `groupID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'μοναδικό μέσω ευρετηρίου UQ - για χρήση ως FKey στον Lessons',
  `periodID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FKey από Periods',
  `subjectID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FKey από Subjects',
  `groupNo` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ο αριθμός της ομάδας (εργαστηριακής, κτλ)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`periodID`, `subjectID`, `groupNo`),
  INDEX `fk_Groups_Periods_idx` (`periodID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Groups_Subject1_idx` (`subjectID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `groupID_UNIQUE` (`groupID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Groups_Periods`
    FOREIGN KEY (`periodID`)
    REFERENCES `wp_utt_periods` (`periodID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Groups_Subjects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`)
    REFERENCES `wp_utt_subjects` (`subjectID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_teachers` (
  `teacherID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `surname` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(35) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teacherID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_classrooms` (
  `classroomID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('Δ','Ε') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Διαλέξεων, Εργαστηρίου',
  `is_available` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classroomID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_utt_lessons` (
  `groupID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FKey από Groups',
  `classroomID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FKey από Classrooms',
  `teacherID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FKey από Teachers',
  `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'το date part καθορίζει την ημερομηνία και το time part την ώρα',
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupID`, `classroomID`, `teacherID`, `datetime`),
  INDEX `fk_Lesson_Classrooms1_idx` (`classroomID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Lesson_Teachers1_idx` (`teacherID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `datetime_classroom_UNIQUE` (`datetime` ASC, `classroomID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `datetime_teacher_UNIQUE` (`datetime` ASC, `teacherID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `datetime_group_UNIQUE` (`datetime` ASC, `groupID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lessons_Classrooms`
    FOREIGN KEY (`classroomID`)
    REFERENCES `wp_utt_classrooms` (`classroomID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lessons_Teachers`
    FOREIGN KEY (`teacherID`)
    REFERENCES `wp_utt_teachers` (`teacherID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lessons_Groups1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`groupID`)
    REFERENCES `wp_utt_groups` (`groupID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? If you simply run those scripts on mysql, do they work?

Comment: Yes the script directly on mysql works. I don't get any errors, it just does not create the last 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

dbDelta is notoriously fussy about how SQL is formatted. [According to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table):

- You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
- You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
- You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
- **You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.**
- Field types must be all lowercase. SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase

Comment: I corrected everything this list says but same results. Only the 4 tables are created.